# Display a clip for a ListView

Tags: android, listview, clip

servas,

how can i display the clip on the right side for scrolling a listview, like in the contacts list?

ciao
  H.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enable the fast scroll thumb see [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android%3afastScrollEnabled)

- Salil